# How to pass a dictionary value as a variable which holds another dictionary

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
var manifest = {
    "product": "onetouch",

    "routes": [
        {
            "title": "Meters and Monitoring",
            "manifest": "metersAndMonitoring"
        }
    ]
}
```

The value for the manifest key is actually another variable that holds another dictionary, as so:

```
var metersAndMonitoring = {
        "question" : "How can we help your patients with blood glucose monitoring?",

        "matrix" : [
            {
                "fileURL" : "slides/3.1_meters_and_monitoring/meters_and_monitoring.html",
                "cssURL" : "slides/3.1_meters_and_monitoring/css/meters_and_monitoring.css",
                "title" : "Meters and Monitoring",
                "thumbnail" : "slides/3.1_meters_and_monitoring/thumbnail.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
```

When I access manifest.routes[0].manifest I get the value "metersAndMonitoring" as I should. However, what I want is then to be able to `console.log(metersAndMonitoring)` and get the output of the dictionary I assigned to that variable. All I currently get is the key as a string.

So my question is, how can I access the key in the first dictionary, and use it as the variable of the same string that I have used for the second dictionary?

Comment: Depending on scoping you can do `window[manifest.routes[0].manifest]`

Comment: Yes @Ram that is corrct